# Launcher.LaunchUriAsync does not work on Xamarin Forms UWP

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am getting a string from an API and I need to open this string using the standard windows notepad.

I tried:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(@"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"));
```

But nothing happened at all.

Comment: Even if it worked, Notepad only opens files, not strings.

Comment: I understand it. The problem is that even an empty notepad does not open. And I said about the line in order to make it clear why I need it.

But thanks anyway, maybe this information will be useful to someone someday.

Comment: I believe you asked this yesterday and it was closed as a duplicate.  Please do not repost questions.  The accepted answer on the linked question explains exactly why what you are trying to do won’t work

Comment: You read the essence of the question more carefully. It's not a duplicate, it's a completely different question. In that question, Launcher.LaunchUriAsync is the solution. And here I am looking for possible reasons that this method does not work.